# Constructive learning models that can run (predict) fairly well on a Raspberry pi?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, references, supervised-learning, computer-vision

I'm looking for a model that is based on constructive learning and will do it's predictions live (via video camera) on the Raspberry Pi 4 Model B, either trained on a PC or pre-trained, I found out about the SIMclr family but I haven't found anything about people using it on their mobile/Pi devices (I'm not performing a trial & error because of time constraint).

Any help, insights and links to online courses about the topic will be appreciated.